# Divide and conquer: IndexSearch

Tags: recurrence, divide-and-conquer

i solved the following task by myself:

Give an algorithm to find an index i such that 1 <= i <= n and A[i] = i provide such an index exists. If there are any such indexes, algorithm can return any of them.

I used the divide and conquer approach and as result i get:

```
public static int IndexSearch(int []A, int l, int r) {
  if (l>r)
     return -1;
  int m = (l+r)/2;  
  IndexSearch(A, l, m-1); 
  IndexSearch(A, m+1, r);
  if (A[m]==m)
     return m;
  else
     return -1;
}
```

First wanted to ask if it is correct? I guess yes....

What is the recursion T(n) in this case?

I presume:

2T(n/2) + O(1) ----> is it right? can one explain me in detailed way how to solve the recurrence applying the Master Theorem ?

a=2 b=2 f(n)=1 n^logba = n ---> n vs 1 so we have CASE 1 which leads to O(n) -> ???? right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It most certainly is not correct.

Since you ignore the return-values of your recursive calls, your program really only  checks if `A[m] == m` in your very first call and returns `-1` if that is not the case.

The "obvious" solution would be something like:

```
public static int IndexSearch(int []A, int l, int r) {
  for i in range(1, length(A))
    if (A[i] == i)
      return i
  return -1
}
```

Also it is a very clear solution, so maybe that's to be preferred over a more sophisticated one.

I am sorry, I cannot help you with your other questions.

EDIT: This should work. It is written in Python, but it should be easy enough to understand.
The point about divide and conquer is to reduce the problem to a point where the solution is obvious. In our case, that would be the list with only one element.
The only difficulty here is passing back the return values.

```
def index(l, a, b):
    if a == b: #The basecase, we consider a list with only one element
        if l[a] == a:
            return a
        else: return -1

    #Here we actually break up
    m = (a+b)/2

    i1 = index(l, a, m)
    if i1 != -1:
        return i1

    i2 = index(l, m+1, b)
    if i2 != -1:
        return i2

    return -1
```

Here is an example output:

```
l = [1,2,3,3,5,6,7,8,9]
print index(l, 0, len(l)-1)

Output: 3
```

Hope that helps.

EDIT: Finding all occurences actually leads to a much nicer solution:

```
def index(l, a, b):     
    if a == b:
        if l[a] == a:
            return [a]
        else:
            return []

    m = (a+b)/2
    return index(l, a, m) + index(l, m+1, b)
```

Which has as ouput:

```
l = [1,2,3,3,5,6,7,8,8]
print "Found " , index(l, 0, len(l)-1), " in " , l

Found  [3, 8]  in  [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
```

and

```
l = range(0,5)
print "Found " , index(l, 0, len(l)-1), " in " , l

Found  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  in  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I think that makes for a nice, pure solution ;-)

Comment: Thank u for ur effort! it works when u have the case where u have 1 element equal the index, but what if I want to print all elements with equal array index? Try l = [1,2,3,3,4,6,7,8,9]...it will print only one element.

Comment: In your solution you are using stdout to collect the indices, which is fine, but is not very reusable. Also it is a bit like cheating if you want to really implement a divide and conquer algorithm ;-) The "Collect Results"-part is important, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would be a possible solution where i print out all possibile elements where value=index.

```
public static int IndexSearch(int []A, int l, int r) {

 if (l>r)
   return -1;


 //Divide into subproblems
 int m = (l+r)/2;  

 //Conquer and find solution to subproblems recursively
 IndexSearch(A, l, m-1); 
 IndexSearch(A, m+1, r);

 //Combine solutions of subproblems to the orignal solution of the problem 
 if (A[m]==m)
   System.out.println(m);

 return 1;
```

}